# Get rownames to column names and put data together from rows to columns with the same name

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
X      ID    X1      X2      X3      X4      X5
BIL   1    1        2        7      1       5
Date 1    12.2     13.5     1.1     26.9    7.9
Year  1    2012    2013     2020    1999    2017
BIL   2    7        9       2        1      5
Date 2    12.2     13.5     1.1     26.9    7.9
Year  2   2022    2063     2000    1989    2015
BIL   3   1        2        7      1       5
Date 3   12.2     13.5     1.1     26.9    7.9
Year  3  2012    2013     2020    1999    2017
```

I would like to transform it so that I get a new df with BIL  Date  Year  as column names and the values listed in the rows below for example

```
     ID  BIL   Date   Year
1     1    1     12.2    2012
2     1    2     13.5    2013
3     1    7
4     1    1
5     1    5
6     2    7    12.2     2022
7     2    9    13.5     2063
```

Any help would really be appreciated!

Edit: Is there any way to also add a grouping variable like I added above

Comment: Just to be sure, your data has duplicateed items, you want to keep them ? (ex: bil = 5, date = 7.9, year = 2017)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This strategy will work.

- create an ID column by equating first column name with X.
- transform into long format, deselect unwanted column (your original variable names) using `names_to = NULL` argument
- transform back into wide, this time using correct variable names
- collect multiple instances into `list` column using `values_fn = list` argument in `pivot_wider`
- unnest all except `ID`

```r
df <- read.table(text = 'X      X1      X2      X3      X4      X5
BIL   1        2        7      1       5
Date 12.2     13.5     1.1     26.9    7.9
Year  2012    2013     2020    1999    2017
BIL   7        9       2        1      5
Date 12.2     13.5     1.1     26.9    7.9
Year  2022    2063     2000    1989    2015
BIL   1        2        7      1       5
Date 12.2     13.5     1.1     26.9    7.9
Year  2012    2013     2020    1999    2017', header = T)

library(tidyverse)

df %>% mutate(ID = cumsum(X == df[1,1])) %>%
  pivot_longer(!c(X,ID), names_to = NULL) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(ID), names_from = X, values_from = value, values_fn = list) %>%
  unnest(!ID)
#> # A tibble: 15 x 4
#>       ID   BIL  Date  Year
#>    <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     1     1  12.2  2012
#>  2     1     2  13.5  2013
#>  3     1     7   1.1  2020
#>  4     1     1  26.9  1999
#>  5     1     5   7.9  2017
#>  6     2     7  12.2  2022
#>  7     2     9  13.5  2063
#>  8     2     2   1.1  2000
#>  9     2     1  26.9  1989
#> 10     2     5   7.9  2015
#> 11     3     1  12.2  2012
#> 12     3     2  13.5  2013
#> 13     3     7   1.1  2020
#> 14     3     1  26.9  1999
#> 15     3     5   7.9  2017
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

This will also give you same results

```
df %>% mutate(ID = cumsum(X == df[1,1])) %>%
  pivot_longer(!c(X,ID)) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(ID, name), names_from = X, values_from = value) %>%
  select(-name)
```

Comment: X     ID    X1      X2      X3      X4      X5
BIL     1    1        2        7      1       5
Date  1   12.2     13.5     1.1     26.9    7.9
Year   1   2012    2013     2020    1999    2017
BIL    2      7        9       2        1      5
Date 2    12.2     13.5     1.1     26.9    7.9
Year  2   2022    2063     2000    1989    2015
BIL    3   1        2        7      1       5
Date  3   12.2     13.5     1.1     26.9    7.9
Thank you for your quick response, is there any way to add a grouping variable thats in an additional column so I know which ID the data belonged to?

Comment: Yes exactly I added it to my question

Answer (score 1):

Get the data in long format, create a unique row number for each value in `X` column and get it back in wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -X) %>%
  group_by(X) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = X, values_from = value) %>%
  select(-row, -name)

#     BIL  Date  Year
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1  12.2  2012
# 2     2  13.5  2013
# 3     7   1.1  2020
# 4     1  26.9  1999
# 5     5   7.9  2017
# 6     7  12.2  2022
# 7     9  13.5  2063
# 8     2   1.1  2000
# 9     1  26.9  1989
#10     5   7.9  2015
#11     1  12.2  2012
#12     2  13.5  2013
#13     7   1.1  2020
#14     1  26.9  1999
#15     5   7.9  2017
```

In `data.table` with `melt` + `dcast`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(melt(setDT(df), id.vars = 'X'), rowid(X)~X, value.var = 'value')
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(X = c("BIL", "Date", "Year", "BIL", "Date", "Year", 
"BIL", "Date", "Year"), X1 = c(1, 12.2, 2012, 7, 12.2, 2022, 
1, 12.2, 2012), X2 = c(2, 13.5, 2013, 9, 13.5, 2063, 2, 13.5, 
2013), X3 = c(7, 1.1, 2020, 2, 1.1, 2000, 7, 1.1, 2020), X4 = c(1, 
26.9, 1999, 1, 26.9, 1989, 1, 26.9, 1999), X5 = c(5, 7.9, 2017, 
5, 7.9, 2015, 5, 7.9, 2017)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R option using `reshape` (first `wide` and then `long`)

```
p <- reshape(
  transform(
    df,
    id = ave(X, X, FUN = seq_along)
  ),
  direction = "wide",
  idvar = "id",
  timevar = "X"
)

q <- reshape(
  setNames(p, gsub("(.*)\\.(.*)", "\\2.\\1", names(p))),
  direction = "long",
  idvar = "id",
  varying = -1
)
```

and you will see

```
     id time BIL Date Year
1.X1  1   X1   1 12.2 2012
2.X1  2   X1   7 12.2 2022
3.X1  3   X1   1 12.2 2012
1.X2  1   X2   2 13.5 2013
2.X2  2   X2   9 13.5 2063
3.X2  3   X2   2 13.5 2013
1.X3  1   X3   7  1.1 2020
2.X3  2   X3   2  1.1 2000
3.X3  3   X3   7  1.1 2020
1.X4  1   X4   1 26.9 1999
2.X4  2   X4   1 26.9 1989
3.X4  3   X4   1 26.9 1999
1.X5  1   X5   5  7.9 2017
2.X5  2   X5   5  7.9 2015
3.X5  3   X5   5  7.9 2017
```

Answer (score 1):

You may `unlist`, `matrix` and coerce it `as.data.frame`, use some cells for `setNames`.

```
setNames(as.data.frame(t(matrix(unlist(dat[-1]), 3, 15))), dat[1:3, 1])
#    BIL Date Year
# 1    1 12.2 2012
# 2    7 12.2 2022
# 3    1 12.2 2012
# 4    2 13.5 2013
# 5    9 13.5 2063
# 6    2 13.5 2013
# 7    7  1.1 2020
# 8    2  1.1 2000
# 9    7  1.1 2020
# 10   1 26.9 1999
# 11   1 26.9 1989
# 12   1 26.9 1999
# 13   5  7.9 2017
# 14   5  7.9 2015
# 15   5  7.9 2017
```

If less hardcoded wanted, use:

```
m <- length(unique(dat$X))
n <- ncol(dat[-1]) * m
setNames(as.data.frame(t(matrix(unlist(dat[-1]), m, n))), dat[1:m, 1])
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- read.table(header=T, text='X      X1      X2      X3      X4      X5
BIL   1        2        7      1       5
Date 12.2     13.5     1.1     26.9    7.9
Year  2012    2013     2020    1999    2017
BIL   7        9       2        1      5
Date 12.2     13.5     1.1     26.9    7.9
Year  2022    2063     2000    1989    2015
BIL   1        2        7      1       5
Date 12.2     13.5     1.1     26.9    7.9
Year  2012    2013     2020    1999    2017
')
```